# Moving files from source to destination in categories

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am currently learning bash script and trying to write a script which moves files from the source to a destination directory and categorises the files based on the first letter and creates a subdirectory based on the first letter.

Categories:

- A-F
- G-L
- M-R
- S-Z
- #

This is what I have written so far and I'm not sure how to proceed further:

**move.sh**

```
echo "Enter the source"
read SOURCE

echo "Enter the destination"
read DESTINATION

for file in $SOURCE;do
    case ${file:0:1} in
      {a..f} ) echo "Belongs to A-F";
        if [ -d $DESTINATION/A-F ]
        then mv file $DESTINATION/A-F
        else mkdir $DESTINATION/A-F
      {g..l} ) echo "Belongs to G-L";
        if [ -d $DESTINATION/G-L ]
        then mv file $DESTINATION/G-L
        else mkdir $DESTINATION/G-L
      {m..r} ) echo "Belongs to M-R";
        if [ -d $DESTINATION/M-R ]
        then mv file $DESTINATION/M-R
        else mkdir $DESTINATION/M-R
      {s..z} ) echo "Belongs to S-Z";
        if [ -d $DESTINATION/S-Z ]
        then mv file $DESTINATION/S-Z
        else mkdir $DESTINATION/S-Z
        { } ) echo "Belongs to #";
        if [ -d $DESTINATION/# ]
        then mv file $DESTINATION/#
        else mkdir $DESTINATION/#
    esac
exit 0
```

Example:

I have downloaded files in the Downloads directory

> aa1.jpg, gg2.mp3, zo1.mkv, 01010.pdf

```
sh move.sh 


Enter the source
/Downloads

Enter the destination
/Documents
```

After Running the script, I should get:

```
/Documents/#/01010.pdf
/Documents/A-F/aa1.jpg
/Documents/G-L/gg2.mp3
/Documents/S-Z/zo1.mkv
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I am not sure how to proceed with my bash script and if what I'm writing makes any sense

Comment: You are asking about how can you write a better one? thats basically opinion based I guess.

Comment: Your script doesn't make any sense, and neither does the example input you gave. This is not a good question for AskUbuntu, since it's too broad.

Comment: What's your question? What are you trying to achieve? Could you please [edit] your question post to clarify? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed some mistakes in your script:

This should produce the result you are looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the source"
read SOURCE

echo "Enter the destination"
read DESTINATION

for file in $SOURCE/*; do
  base=`basename "${file}"`
  letter=${base:0:1}

  case $letter in
    [a-f]) echo "A-F";
     if [ -d "$DESTINATION/A-F" ]; then
       echo "Moving file..."
       mv $file "$DESTINATION/A-F"
     else
      mkdir -p "$DESTINATION/A-F";
     fi
    ;;
    [g-l]) echo "G-L"
      if [ -d "$DESTINATION/G-L" ]; then
        echo "Moving file..."
        mv $file "$DESTINATION/G-L"
      else
        mkdir -p "$DESTINATION/G-L"
      fi
    ;;
    [m-r]) echo "M-R"
      if [ -d "$DESTINATION/M-R" ]; then
        echo "Moving file..."
        mv $file "$DESTINATION/M-R"
      else
        mkdir -p "$DESTINATION/M-R"
      fi
    ;;
    [s-z]) echo "S-Z";
      if [ -d "$DESTINATION/S-Z" ]; then
        echo "Moving file..."
        mv $file "$DESTINATION/S-Z"
      else
        mkdir -p "$DESTINATION/S-Z";
      fi
    ;;
    *) echo "-"
      if [ -d "$DESTINATION/-" ]; then
        echo "Moving file..."
        mv $file "$DESTINATION/-"
      else
        mkdir -p "$DESTINATION/-";
      fi
  esac
done
```

Comment: If the destination doesn't exist, the file doesn't move. Is that intentional?

Comment: @wjandrea Yes, do you have some suggestion?

Comment: @Jsdude This is an improvement, but still not ideal: `if [ -d "$DESTINATION/A-F" ] || mkdir -p "$DESTINATION/A-F"; then echo "Moving file..."; mv $file "$DESTINATION/A-F"; fi`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest making the directories **before** trying to move the files, not after. Also, skip checking for the directory's existence, just use

```
mkdir -p
```

Also I don't think you need all those complex conditionals, although simplicity is in the mind of the beholder I guess. To me, something like the following seems simpler.

```
#!/bin/bash

# repeats until you enter a valid directory
while [ ! -d "$DESTINATION_ANY_VALID_FORM" ]; do
      read -p "Enter destination directory:" DESTINATION_ANY_VALID_FORM
done

# canonicalizes directory name into a standard form
DESTINATION="$(readlink -f "$DESTINATION_ANY_VALID_FORM")"

# same deal for source
while [ ! -d "$SOURCE_ANY_VALID_FORM" ]; do
      read -p "Enter source directory:" SOURCE_ANY_VALID_FORM
done

SOURCE="$(readlink -f "$SOURCE_ANY_VALID_FORM")"

# makes the directories you want if they don't exist already - 
# conditionals aren't needed.
mkdir -p $DESTINATION/A-F
mkdir -p $DESTINATION/G-L
mkdir -p $DESTINATION/M-R
mkdir -p $DESTINATION/S-Z
mkdir -p $DESTINATION/#

# And then move the files any way you want. There must eleventy-twelve ways. 
# I was wrong thinking wildcards would be easy. 
# That is actually kind of hard. 
# The following is easy to write and understand, but there are more efficient ways.

ls -w1 "$SOURCE" | grep ^[a-f,A-F] | while read FILE ; do
       mv --verbose --backup --target-directory="$DESTINATION/A-F" "$SOURCE/$FILE"  
done

ls -w1 "$SOURCE" | grep ^[g-l,G-L] | while read FILE ; do
       mv --verbose --backup --target-directory="$DESTINATION/G-L" "$SOURCE/$FILE"  
done

ls -w1 "$SOURCE" | grep ^[m-r,M-R] | while read FILE ; do
       mv --verbose --backup --target-directory="$DESTINATION/M-R" "$SOURCE/$FILE"
done

ls -w1 "$SOURCE" | grep ^[s-z,S-Z] | while read FILE ; do
       mv --verbose --backup --target-directory="$DESTINATION/S-Z" "$SOURCE/$FILE"
done

ls -w1 "$SOURCE" | grep ^[0-9] | while read FILE ; do
       mv --verbose --backup --target-directory="$DESTINATION/#" "$SOURCE/$FILE"
done
```

paste-bin version: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24540558/

Comment: I suggest replacing `ls -w1 "$SOURCE" | grep ^[m-r,M-R] | while read FILE` with `for file in "$source"/*`, and make all your variable names lowercase to avoid overwriting environment variables.

Comment: Just to make that a little more explicit: If that replacement is made (and it probably has at least one advantage: not being dependent on the stability of the output format of ls), then the logic of what follows the pipe must be reproduced in the for loop.  As for the variables, overwriting any hypothetical environment variables is only relevant in the process running this script. The variables established do not persist after the script finishes. They do not propagate to the environment outside of this script even while it is running. The only way I can see that would matter would be if . . .

Comment: @wjandrea  The only way I can see that would matter would be if both the hypothetical environment variables and the locally established variables were used in the script, which is not the case. The recommendation can be justified on the basis of 'it's a good habit" since occasionally the conditions in which  it is relevant might occur. Offsetting that is a perceptual issue. I like variables to stand out. It makes the script easier to read for me. I sometimes use camel case which addresses both concerns. Please correct me if you think I'm wrong about the technical aspect of this.